# SQL: group by number with error margin

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table of clients with their birth year:

- Koen Peeters, 1987
- Sara Stas, 1989
- Karel Tosijn, 1986
- Koen Peeters, 1988
- Koen Peeters, 1950

I want to create a new table grouping the clients by name, and by year.

But the problem is that there is a -1,+1 error margin on the year of birth. So Koen Peeters born in 1987 is the same as Koen Peeters in 1988, but the Koen Peeters born in 1950 is a different Koen Peeters.

Is it possible to do this in SQL? It is kind of a fuzzy group by?

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: I have been reading a lot with taking the modulus the year of birth with two, but it doesn't work as 1981 sometimes needs to be matched with 1980 and sometimes with 1982. So I really don't see a solution.

Comment: As davidhigh commented below: "Given a Koen Peters in each of the years 1980,1981, .. 1988". What's the expected result in that case?

Answer (score 2):

```
SQL>create table t (n varchar(30), y int);
SQL>insert into t values ('Koen Peeters',1987);
SQL>insert into t values ('Sara Stas',1989);
SQL>insert into t values ('Karel Tosijn',1986);
SQL>insert into t values ('Koen Peeters',1988);
SQL>insert into t values ('Koen Peeters',1950);
SQL>select t1.*
SQL&from t t1
SQL&where not exists (select 1 from t t2
SQL&                  where t1.n = t2.n
SQL&                    and t1.y = t2.y + 1);
n                                        y
============================== ===========
Koen Peeters                          1987
Sara Stas                             1989
Karel Tosijn                          1986
Koen Peeters                          1950

                  4 rows found
```

Simply pick a clients when there are no one with same name but 1 year older. (Will only pick the older Koen Peeters from 1987/1988.)

Do `SELECT DISTINCT` if needed.

Comment: Given a `Koen Peters` in each of the years `1980,1981, .. 1988`, this will pick only the `1988`-guy.

Comment: Good point! But what's the expected result in that case? Maybe the question's sample data and expected result should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic expressions in `group by`. So the question is, how can you transform a number to make it a bit "wider" for grouping purposes?

Well, reducing the space can easily be done by division:

```
year / 2
```

This will mean that `1980` and `1981` will be grouped in the same group, while `1980` and `1982` will not. But it isn't really `-1 - +1` - it will be `+1` for `1980` and `1981`, and `-1` for `1981` and `1980`, while it will not work at all for `1980` versus `1979`. So we need to dig deeper - how do we *really* solve this?

The basic problem is that if it were actually possible to group `1980` in *either* the `1979` group, *or* the `1980`, *or* the `1981` group, you could pretty much expand this to cover every single possible value (imagine if you had the same author name with years `1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, ...`). There's no X:1 mapping between the original result set and the grouped result set, you're actually trying to make the same input value belong in multiple different output values.

I'm pretty sure relational algebra simply doesn't allow you to do this. What I'd do instead is go author by author procedurally (e.g. using a cursor or just a bunch of `select`s), and tag the ones that should belong together with the same ID (going row by row, it's easy to determine all the other authors with the same name but having `abs(myYear - hisYear) <= 1`). By keeping to this every time you add a new author, you can easily group the authors by actual equality, rather than "fuzzy group by"'s.

In pseudo-code, this would be something like

```
go row by row
 find author with the same name, with `abs(myYear - hisYear) <= 1` and ID not null
  if exists, update myself with found ID
  otherwise, update myself with a new unique ID
```

This could of course be optimized, but unless you have a good reason to do so, I'd just stick with the simpler code - this is exactly the kind of thing where it's very easy to make a stupid little mistake that ruins everything :)

And on an insert trigger to the book table, just do the same thing with just the newly inserted rows.

Comment: +1, that is a good point. One could solve this (somewhat ambiguously) by setting up one fixed raster (1986, 1988, 1990, ...), and further specify which years are mapped onto which grid-points.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something very similar as you described, going over row by row, with R but it is incredible slow (I have hundreds of tables with around 200.000 unique clients). Somebody told me I could do this faster in SQL, that is why I asked.

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek Yeah, the problem is your data isn't quite normalized. The `year` column can represent multiple different values at the same time, in effect. But you only have to do this once, which should be good enough. And it would be very useful to do this all in an SQL procedure, rather than doing it from some client code - you'll save yourself a lot of copying and roundtrips to the database and back.

Comment: Can you maybe point me to some w3 schools pages about the SQL statements I will be needing? There is lots of new commands in the pseudo code, is this SQL?

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek No, that's just pseudo-code. What DB engine are you using? Procedural SQL is even more different between DB engines than plain SQL :)

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek Yeah, I can't really help you with that. And it doesn't make for a good StackOverflow question either. What you're mainly looking for is a cursor (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/) - that will allow you to iterate row by row, and then you just use the usual `select`+`update` combo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer which builds up on that of @Luaan. Due to the problem he mentions, it might be appropriate to set up a fixed time grid (with a temporal distance of two years), and map all years smaller than some gridpoint to the next higher (or lower) gridpoint.

```
WITH my_table AS
(
SELECT 'Koen Peeters' AS NAME, 1987 AS YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'Sara Stas', 1989 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'Karel Tosijn', 1986 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'Koen Peeters', 1988 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'Koen Peeters', 1950 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT name
     , CASE WHEN MOD(year,2)=1 THEN year+1 ELSE year END AS adjusted_year
FROM my_table
```

That gives

```
Koen Peeters    1950
(Koen Peeters   1987)  -> gets mapped to 1988 and then removed by the DISTINCT
Karel Tosijn    1986
Koen Peeters    1988
Sara Stas       1990
```

Of course, that still doesn't solve the problem with another `'Kroen Peters'` born in `1986`. For this you could adapt the temporal grid, or you can apply another similar operation again.

But as @Luaan says, you have to make a decision here, otherwise there is a large ambiguity when you have eleven `'Kroen Peters'` in `1980` to `1990`, for example.